# upgrading to new react-native version and doing pod install throws an error CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "SocketRocket"

Tags: react-native, cocoapods, socketrocket

i tried to update react-native version to latest *0.72.3* and run `pod install` which resulted in next error

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "SocketRocket":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    SocketRocket (= 0.6.0, ~> 0.6.0)

  In Podfile:
    React-Core/RCTWebSocket (from `../node_modules/react-native/`) was resolved to 0.72.3, which depends on
      SocketRocket (= 0.6.1)

Specs satisfying the `SocketRocket (= 0.6.0, ~> 0.6.0), SocketRocket (= 0.6.1)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

what can be the issue and is there a normal way around it?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me, inside ios folder,

bundle exec pod install --repo-update

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error. Manage to fix it by deleting the lockfile and pod folder, and run `pod install --repo-update`. Had deployment target set to `12.4`.

Comment: I had to do `bundle exec pod install --repo-update` in ios folder

Answer (score 0):

Update the platform in the Podfile to at least iOS 11:

`platform :ios, '11.0'`

Reference the recent SocketRocket requirement change at https://github.com/facebookincubator/SocketRocket/commit/6637623b392a1ee3f1f2ce8c4a6bfcc75dd394e9

Comment: Minimum deployment version is set to 12.4

Answer (score 0):

in iOS folder, by applying this command its work

```
bundle exec pod install --repo-update
```

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions here didn't work for me, but did was

pod update SocketRocket